# How to route an array of parameters in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I´m trying to route an array of parameters in my Rails 3 app but i keep getting a 404 error.

Here´s the ajax request in my JS file:

```
var url = '/arrayquery?kind[]=startup&kind[]=investor'

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "text"

}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

My routing:

```
match 'arrayquery/:kind', :to => 'home#arrayquery'
```

And my controller method:

```
def arrayquery
  @players = Player.where("kind = ?", params[:kind])
end
```

My browser keep throwing this line:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/arrayquery?kind[]=startup&kind[]=investor"
```

Does anybody know why there´s no matching route for the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route you've defined in your routes file is looking for,

```
http://localhost:3000/arrayquery/KIND?param=value&param=value
```

Try changing the route to,

```
match 'arrayquery', :to => 'home#arrayquery'
```